# Should I use given resolution or calculate resolution based on the max range and number of sig bits?

Tags: avionics, arinc-429

In ARINC429, Should I use given resolution or calculate resolution based on the max range and number of sig bits given?

ForeExample, to calculate Ambient Static Pressure (Label-203, Equipment ID - 10A),

Given Range (Min to Max): 1.5 to 20

Given No of SIG. bits: 11

Given Resolution: 0.016

Calculated Resolution:

```
MAX RANGE / 2 ^ (No of SIG. bits) 
20 / (2^11) 
20 / 2048 
= 0.009765625.
```

**Question 1**: What will be the Ambient Static Pressure value if all the 11 bits are 0.

**Question 2**: Should I use given resolution or calculated resolution for my LSB value?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to recognize the the resolution provided in the ARINC 429 spec is an **approximation** so you can't necessarily use that exactly as it is.

**From the commentary in section 2.1.6 Data Standards**

> For convenience, all binary word ranges in
> Attachment 2 are shown as whole binary numbers
> rather than such numbers less one least significant
> bit value. **Also, the resolutions shown are
> approximate only. Accurate resolutions can be
> determined, if required, by reference to the range
> values and numbers of significant bits for the words of
> interest.**

In order to provide a range of 1.5 to 20, the label will have an actual range of 0-32, which with 11 significant bits, will provide an actual resolution of $\frac{32}{2048} = 0.015625$ (approximated to 0.016 in the ARINC 429 spec)